# cluster scheduling: that describes scheduling speculative threads unto clusters

Tags: multithreading, cluster-computing, scheduler

Update for clarification:

T1 is scheduled unto a cluster and sequentially touches memory locations 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then back to 1.

T2 is scheduled concurrently unto the same cluster and sequentially touches memory locations 6, 2, 3, and then tries to write to 1 while T1 is still depending on memory location 1 to be what it was before.

I guess before T2 writes to memory location 1, T2 should wait or maybe wait to be executed onto the cluster until T1 is finished.

Is it possible to determine what memory locations T1 needs to be consistent, like memory location 1, and store this information in a table. That way, before T2 is executed unto the cluster, T2 can check a table for memory locations that it needs to write to, sees that T1 depends on memory location 1, and therefore delay the execution of T2 unto the cluster?

kind of what like chapter 3.2 shows in the below PDF.

Thanks for any help.

---

I am researching a topic for a computer science class on how we can take an idea and improve upon it. My topic I choose is cluster scheduling.

I've been reading papers such as http://apt.cs.man.ac.uk/people/yiapanip/taco13yiapanis.pdf

It seems as though when threads are scheduled, checking for conflicts with other threads accessing the same memory location, happens after a thread writes and commits to memory. Is there a way to determine beforehand a thread wants to commit?

Is there information out there (keywords to know) that keeps a table of memory locations that are being writing to by threads so that subsequent threads can be scheduled unto the cluster after checking only memory locations that are being written to by the executing threads? If there is a write to a memory location, a subsequent thread needs, that thread is stalled, but if the memory location is not being written to, therefore would not be in a table, the subsequent thread may be scheduled unto that cluster.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I think you need to clarify your topic and thinking a bit: 1) I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by' Is there a way to determine beforehand a thread wants to commit?'. 2) Cluster Scheduling, is this a technique, or a problem domain [I work in speculation, not in scheduling mostly]? 3) It sounds like you'd like to know the write set of an un-executed thread in order to minimize conflicts on scheduling... this is possible to *approximate* in some cases, but strictly speaking requires seeing the future!

Comment: updated for clarification, thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into software transactional memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not 100% sure of precisely what you mean by cluster, but here's an answer based on a shared memory machine and a simple Software based TLS system*.

---

To choose to delay T2's execution, you need to know the read and write sets of T2, and compare them to the in-flight sets for all executing threads.

In general, this isn't possible, as the read-and-write sets can be data dependent:

```
a[i] = b[c[i]]
```

Having said that, it may be possible to succeed with either a static approximation, or a using profiling.

---

Some suggestions as far as possible inspiration, and things you're going to need to keep in mind

- Remember: Order of accesses matters: RAW,RAR,WAR.
- An interesting citation for you to track down:

  > Arnamoy Bhattacharyya. 2013. Do Inputs Matter? Using Data-dependence Profiling to Evaluate Thread Level Speculation in BlueGene/Q. To appear in Parallel architectures and compilation techniques (PACT '13)

  Which suggests you might be able to get away with minimal worry about input dependence.

* Software TLS,  as this whole conversation would be moot on a [hardware speculation platform.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2481794).